# SharePoint 2010 Survey cascading question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Here is the functionality I am trying to achieve.

I have a survey with two dropdowns. U.S. States and U.S. Cities.

The first dropdown lists all 50 U.S. States the next question the survey lists 500 of cities in the U.S.

Based on what state the user selects, Ohio for example,  I would like the second dropdown to only list the cities for that states. In the case of Ohio, listed would be Cleveland, Cincinnati, Columbus, Dayton, Toledo, etc.

How can I accomplish this in a SharePoint 2010 Survey?

Answer (score 0):

I think the very simplest solution to achieve your goals is the [SPCascadeDropdowns function](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns) of the [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/). This approach is based on the built-in SharePoint web services on the server side and JavaScript on the client side. That means you should not install any custom field types or other assemblies on the server.

Comment: I apologize if I was not more specific. I was primarily looking to accomplish this in a SharePoint 2010 survey.

Comment: Yes, I understood it just so as you meant. There is no built-in solution in SP 2010 survays to achive your goal. You shoul edit the survay form either with SharePoint Designer or via the web UI (see this post to learn how to set the form in web part edit mode: https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/trick-the-sharepoint-query-string-url/), add a Content Editor web part to the page and includes the scripts / references that invokes the SPCascadeDropdowns functionality. The survay is a special type of lists, there is no significant difference in the way you can manipulate its fields.